# How to write local notification in iOS 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application in iOS 3.1.3. But there is no facility to write code for local notifications.

Is there any alternative for local notifications in iOS 3.1.3?

Comment: No. Is is simply not a feature that is there in 3.1.3. Why would you want to develop for 3.1.3? That version is _really_ old and there is probably not a significant number of people who still use it.

Comment: But i have a iphone 3g for testing.If u develope an app in ios 3.1.3 then that support all next versios.so iam using that one

Answer (score 1):

Remote notifications is the way you will have to go on iOS 3.1.3, if you really need notifications.

Comment: Remote notifications means push notifications or not

Comment: Remote notifications == push notifications.

Comment: The return value of the above expression is YES ;-)